# Processing a big data in Javascript variables: bad practice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, resources, bigdata

I will need to have an array that should be rearranged from time to time.

The expected size of the array will be let's say thousands of rows 3-4 columns per row. One of the columns will be a integer number which is a sorting key. The sorting will be performed each time user take an action (let's say once in 10 seconds).

Earlier I'd perform this action of a server side with MySQL (which has a bunch well optimized sorting methods). However I decided to consider the possibility of performing this on a client side (in the browser).

This would be a great resource economy for my server however I don't have any experience with such kind of data manipulation and I don't know if it will hang user's browser due to huge CPU or memory usage.

I could test this in my browser but if it will work for me it is no guarantee that it will work well in all browsers for all users.

So I'd say that my question is: *is it a good practice to manipulate a big data in user's browser?*

Comment: Dealing with big data at once is a bad practice in all environments. It consumes many resources in any environment and not just in the user's browser. You need find a better/more efficient way for manipulating them. If you have a sorted array, find the right index, push the item at that position and avoid resorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to measure the time needed to process a sorting operation on your Array on the executing plateforme you have chosen.
then you'll determine if you can sort once 1 ten seconds.
Ask if you need method to measure, I will post as an EDIT of this answer.

As for your arcitecture, I think you can push raw array with Ajax from your server, and let the user sort it in his browser

EDIT : an exemple of time measure for the fullfill of a 10000000 pseudo-random doubles and the calculation of the average value

```
var maxLength = 10000000;
var array = [];
var somme = 0;
var moyenne = 0;
var start = Date.now();
for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
array.push(1023*i/23);
for (var i = 0; i < maxLength; i++)
   somme += array[i];
moyenne = somme/array.length;
var stop = Date.now();
var lasting = stop - start;
console.log(moyenne);
console.log("executing time = " + lasting + " ms");
```

Comment: Hi, Kevin! Thank you for your advize! I thought of measuring on a hardware that I have, but I supposed that it will not be precise (I'd even think that this measurement will vary from time to time). So if you will be able to put in your method in the EDIT so I'd be glad for. Thanks!